# Lightweight Markup Language for Icons

Tags: javascript, icons, markup

Lightweight markup languages are very convenient for hyperlinks and images. But what I am looking for is a language that would help users display icons or smileys on a page (for example on a dashboard).

For example, "flag:red" would display... a red flag. "Light:green" would display a green traffic light. The icons could come from an image library, unicode symbols, or maybe a graphic library.

Does such a language exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Github implemented something similar to this](https://github.com/blog/816-emoji) for their markup. You'd write `:cake:` and get this (in scale with the rest of the text, mind you):

[image: teh cake is a lie]

Unfortunately, the implementation is *not* open-source. However, your idea works great. Implement a simple parser in your language of choice, come up with a rigid syntax and an image library, and go to town!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [reStructuredText](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/rest.html) by adding some "custom interpreted text roles" but if all you want to do it choose icons, you're probably better off with a custom "domain specific language".  How you'd do it is very dependent on the environment you want to use though.